# Is it possible to have list objects be instances of a module and execute a function in that module using "for i in range(dice)"?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly-python

I want to sum a total of dice rolls that I written in another module. Instead of manually changing the amount of dice for each instance, I want to just set it once how many dice and do it. So I wanted to store the instances of the modules in a list and then run the roll function for each time the program loops through the list. Do function instances and module instances work as list objects?

```
from plotly.graph_objs import Bar, Layout
from plotly import offline

from die import Die

#Store the results in a list
results = []

#Set the variable names of the dice
die_1 = Die()
die_2 = Die()
die_3 = Die()

dice = [die_1, die_2, die_3]
dice_num = len(dice)


#Roll them like Vegas
for roll_num in range(1000):
    for i in range(dice):
        f = i in dice
        roll_total = f.roll()
        results.append(roll_total)
```

Comment: Assuming `die.py` defines a class called `Die`, then instances of this class are indeed objects and can be put in a list.  I don't know what you mean by "instances of a module" but from the code it looks like you have instances of a class that happens to be defined in a different module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to make a number of dice and call a method on each:

```
#Store the results in a list
results = []

#Set the variable names of the dice
# Suppose N is a number

dice = [Dice() for _ in range(N)]


#Roll them like Vegas
for roll_num in range(1000):
    for d in dice:
        roll_total = d.roll()
        results.append(roll_total)
```